# How to accsses google api key for google maps android api key version 1

Tags: android, google-api, google-maps-android-api-2, api-key

As you know Google do not support Google Maps API version 1.0 form some days ago. But I had started developing an android application with this API and now when I want to publish it, I can not achieve a Google Map API key. A have some search along some days and find that upgrading to the API version 2 will takes many times.

Is there any way that I access to a API Key for version 1 and  publish my application in it deadline ( it is  2 days later) and then I upgrade to  the second version for my feature updates?

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you generate key for google maps API V1

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/ check the note on the page. If you have a key generated before the date mentioned you can use the same. Now it is not possible. Switch to api v2

Comment: I just have a key for debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Google maps API V1 is deprecated you need to use Google maps API V2. Take a look at the following example by [vogella](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html).It is Simple.This is the last option that you have. So Don't waste time. Just Do it.